# An example of a projective sequence of measures on non-Borel spaces that does not extend to a probability on the product space?

Tags: probability-theory

Daniell proved a theorem on the existence of random sequences (see page 13 of [these notes](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~ismael/files/AdvancedProbability/AdvancedProbability.pdf)):

> Let $(S_n,\mathbf{S_n})$ be a sequence of Borel spaces and let $\mu_n$
>   be a projective sequence of probability measures on $ (S_n:n\in
> > \mathbb{N})$. Then, there's a unique probability measure $ \mathbb{P}$
>   on the product $ \sigma$-algebra of $ \prod_{n\geq 0}S_n$, such that,
>   for all $ n$, for all $ E \in S_0\otimes \cdots\otimes S_n$, 
>   $\mathbb{P}[E\times \prod_{i\geq n+1}S_i] = \mathbb{P}[E]$

I'm trying to find a counterexample when we don't assume that $(S_n,\mathbf{S_n})$ are Borel.

Perhaps the simplest examples of non-Borel spaces are finite measurable spaces for which not all singleton sets are measurable.

[Non-Borel sets](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45165/can-a-non-borel-set-be-a-standard-borel-space) are also non-Borel spaces, but this seems like a complicated way to go. (Quick, relevant question: are all probability measures on such spaces inner regular?)

The main idea of the proof of this theorem seems to be that we can approximate measurable sets on $([0,1],\mathcal{B}[0,1])$ by compact sets, and use the fact that $(S_n:n\in \mathbb{N})$ have the same structure, since they are Borel.

I still don't have a clear idea of which properties any counterexample must satisfy, which is probably why I haven't got very far!

Thank you.

Comment: See H. Wegner, *[On consistency of probability measures](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF00532827)*, Z. Wahrscheinlichkeitstheorie verw. Geb. **27**, Nr. 4, (1973), 335-338, and the references therein.

Comment: @theo: Thank you. The paper refers to the book Measure Theory by Halmos, which has the required example on page 214.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The historically first such example was in a paper by Andersen and Jessen,  [On the introduction of measures in infinite product sets.](http://www.sdu.dk/media/bibpdf/Bind%2020-29%5CBind%5Cmfm-25-4.pdf)
Danske Vid. Selsk., Mat.-Fys. Medd. 25, No.4, 7 S. (1948).