# Projective limit of a sequence of probability spaces

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X_n$ be a projective system of measurable spaces with measurable linking mappings $f_{n+1, n} : X_{n+1} \to X_n$ and projective limit $X = \displaystyle \lim_{\longleftarrow} X_n$ with linking mappings $f_n : X \to X_n$.

1. On the steps $X_n$ let be given a probability measure $P_n$ satisfying the compatibility condition $(f_{n+1,n})_* P_{n+1} = P_n$ for all $n$. Does there exist a probability $P$ on $X$ such that $(f_n)_* P = P_n$? Is this measure $P$ unique?
2. Simpler question: On $X$ let be given probability measures $P$ and $Q$ such that $(f_n)_* P = (f_n)_* Q$ for all $n$. Does it follow that $P = Q$?

Note that I do not assume any topological conditions on the measurable spaces (and linking mappings) neither on the measures $P$ (via regularity), so that the Kolmogoroff extension theorem is not applicable. However, I assume that since the system above is countable (in fact a sequence), these topological constraints should not be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

For 1.: I just found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51967/an-example-of-a-projective-sequence-of-measures-on-non-borel-spaces-that-does-no): without any further regularity conditions, a compatible sequence of probability measures $P_n$ need not have an extension to a probability measure $P$ on $X$. If it has an extension, it is necessarily unique (see 2.)

For 2.: This is true (apply Dynkin's lemma).